# Cross-Compiling with makepkg command

Tags: arch-linux, makepkg

I'm running a x86_64 Arch Linux, now I need to build packages for a i386 Arch Linux,

Is that possible? I already checked `makepkg (8)`, it doesn't seem to support manually selection of package architecture.

I'm doing this for a few AUR packages, and I don't really want to, e.g add CLAGS

Comment: Might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131158/how-to-cross-compile-for-linux-x86-with-linux-amd64-cmake-and-g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [devtools](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/devtools/) package provides a few [helper scripts](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/DeveloperWiki%3aBuilding_in_a_Clean_Chroot#Convenience_Way) to build packages for a different architecture from PKGBUILD files.

Comment: The makechrootpkg solved the problem.

Comment: unfortunately, this solution doesn't work on a traditional system, without systemd, because the makechrootpkg script depends on systemd-nspawn

Comment: Arch Linux always uses systemd, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 4):

This thread sounds like what you're looking for.

- [How to cross compile 32bit packages on Arch64 via distcc?](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=60475)

I'm not that familiar with ArchLinux so I don't understand the specifics but from what I gather it sounds like you can setup a 32-Bit chroot environment on your 64-Bit system, setup a 32-Bit toolchain within it, and build packages in there.

Also this link was referenced and looks to be exactly what you want.

- [Install bundled 32-bit system in Arch64](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch64_Install_bundled_32bit_system)

Comment: First link has dead links inside.